# A pointer to a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having an issue creating a pointer to a multidimensional list. In the case of the single array - no problems output is as it should be. In the case of the multidimensional array - an error message is generated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 3, COLS = 4;
    int list[ROWS][COLS] = { {4, -3, 5, 6}, {5, 1, 7, 2},{-4,6,10,-8}};
    int list2[] = {3, 6, 9, 2};

    int *plist = list;
    int *plist2 = list2;

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            cout << setw(4) << list[row][col] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout <<  *plist  << endl;
    cout <<  *plist2  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp:11:14: error: cannot convert "int (*)[4]" to "int*" in initialization
>   int *plist = list;

Comment: There's no pointers-to-array involved in this code whatsoever. There are only a 1D and a 2D array of `int` and a pointer to `int`. The 1D array decays into `int *` so it can be assigned to `plist`. The 2D array decays into a pointer-to-array (`int (*)[COLS]`) and that is incompatible with `int *`. You could write `int *plist = list[0];` or `int *plist = &list[0][0];` instead.

Comment: The line `int *plist = list;` simply doesn't make sense, and your compiler is doing the best it can to tell you. `list` is an array of arrays of int, and so it decays to a pointer to the first element, i.e. a pointer to an array of ints, and not a pointer to an int. Plain as midnight.

Comment: Better: `for (auto const & row : list) { for (int v : row) { std::cout << v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n'; }`

Comment: when you want to reference variables in an array (single dimension) you specify the pointer and set it equal to the array name - saying this is the memory location where this array begins point here. I want to do the same thing with a two dimensional array. start here/point here. that is all.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Then go with `int (*plist)[COLS] = list;`.

Comment: Thank you I will. Not sure why this is a bad question but glad to have it straitened out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to do, but a 2D array cannot decay to a single pointer. As an example, pointer to array would work, letting the first dimension decay to pointer:

```
int (*plist)[COLS] = list;
```

You can then access the elements as `plist[i][j]`.

Also beware of using names such as `list`, especially if you do something adventurous such as saying `using namespace std;`.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is a pointer to reference the elements in a 2D array.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR that's not gonna work in one step anyway.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR You can access them: `plist[2][3]` etc.

Comment: Yes, i know that plist[2][3] can be used the idea is that i want to use a pointer - i want to be able to work with memory locations - and access the data in the arrays.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR `plist` ***IS*** a pointer. It's a pointer to array. You can't use a single `int *` to traverse all of the elements of the array (when you access out-of-bounds of the very first array, that results in undefined behavior, even though the array is contiguous in memory.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Thus, your last edit is unfortunately **incorrect.**

Comment: @YelizavetaYR You can also make `plist` a pointer to `int`, and make it point to the first element, and then index it as a 1D array. See edit.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, you can't.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because the pointer points to the first element of the first array. When `i` is greater than 0, then this causes an out-of-bounds access of that array.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I cannot see that. It points to the address of the first element. The elements are all contiguous. So what is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63131/discussion-between-the-paramagnetic-croissant-and-juanchopanza).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Unfortunately there are no references to the C++ standard in those links. I will read up on that.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I couldn't find anything in the C++ standard that would unambiguously prove me right, which I take to mean I am wrong. So I removed the contentious paragraph. Unfortunately I cannot delere my answer because it is selected. I did, however, close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza However, you have amended your question, for which I thank you. I'm removing my relevant comments as well.